# Hippo CMS Deployment to tomcat (Blank page shown in Browser, page source available in curl)

Tags: java, tomcat, hippocms

I pretty much followed the instructions on http://www.onehippo.org/library/enterprise/installation-and-configuration/linux-installation-manual.html for configuring a hippo cms instance on tomcat8.

I got it up and running without any ERRORs in the log files but if I query http://localhost:8080/site from my Browser a blank page is shown, but if I look at the source behind the page I see the html code I would expect.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

I was using a the following code (simplified)

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="someurl" />
```

--> no html or script error but nothing displayed in the browser

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="someurl" ></script>
```

works fine (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: If this has resolved your issue why don't you simply accept this answer. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have it running without errors and can see the actual HTML code, then I strongly suspect a client side issue.

I've seen this happening because of JavaScript error(s) that prevents rendering (check that in the developer tools of your browser of choice). Or, maybe you have a browser incompatibility: try using another browser. Could be also that the HTML is slightly malformed, you could try an HTML validator service.